# How do i pull in html content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I wanted to use javascript to pull in html code. I have set up the html code like so;

```
<html>
<div id="tesingCode">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>testOfCodetestOfCodetestOfCodetestOfCode</p>
</div>
</html>
```

then I created a variable like so;

```
var testingTheCode = document.getElementById ("tesingCode");
```

and tried to add the variable to the Polymer project like so;

```
Polymer({

is: 'animated-grid',

behaviors: [
  Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior
],

properties: {

  config: {
    type: Array,
    value: function() {
      return [
        {value: 1, color: 'blue'},
        {value: 2, color: 'red'},
        {value: 3, color: 'blue'},
          {testingTheCode, color: 'green'},
        {value: 5, color: 'yellow'},
        {value: 6, color: 'blue'},
        {value: 7, color: 'red'},
        {value: 8, color: 'green'},
        {value: 9, color: 'yellow'},
        {value: 10, color: 'red'}
      ]
    }
  },
```

The full file is animated-grid.html which is available here...

https://github.com/alistairkb/Coachella/blob/master/animated-grid.html

My overall aim is to add content to the boxes before they have been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, I think you are looking for the innerHTML property

Check out this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5240dsbq/)

You just need to put .innerHTML at the end of your testingcode variable

```
var testingTheCode = document.getElementById ("tesingCode").innerHTML;
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, please post a jsFiddle of your code.

Comment: Don't think adding it to JSFiddle will help me show you how it works since its reliant on server side but here you go. I tried your suggestion then I end up seeing a black screen instead. I have it up on a server for your comparison here too; http://caringforyorkshire.co.uk/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/grid/index.html

Comment: @Alistairkb So you basically want to change the content of the blocks using javascript?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the jsfiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/pngosw4b/
But yes, that exactrly what i need to do